# SQL query to delete XMLTAG element from CLOB

Tags: oracle, clob

```
CREATE TABLE STREAM
  ( PAYLOAD CLOB
  );

    INSERT
    INTO stream VALUES ('<MC><RECORD><CODE>4995908</CODE><TITLE>Adrenocortical </TITLE><ROOT_CODE>380146</ROOT_CODE><MOD>229</MOD></RECORD><RECORD><CODE>69354563</CODE><TITLE> right</TITLE><ROOT_CODE>380146</ROOT_CODE><MOD>230</MOD></RECORD></MC><MT><RECORD><TYPE>LATERALITY</TYPE><TITLES>Laterality</TITLES><MOD><MODIFIER><MCS>69383650</MCS></MODIFIER></MOD></RECORD></MT>')
```

I WANT TO  DELETE the XMLELEMENTS (Adrenocortical  AND  RIGHT< /TITLE>)
from the above row, could not convert into XMLTYPE also.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `dbms_lob` procedures from a PL/SQL block; but with a bit of work you can use XML functionality. The first step is to convert your CLOB to something that can be converted to XMLType, say by wrapping it in a dummy root node:

```
select xmltype('<xml>' || payload || '</xml>') from stream;
```

Then you can use an XQuery or the `deletexml()` function to remove all the `TITLE` nodes:

```
select deletexml(xmltype('<xml>' || payload || '</xml>'), '//TITLE')
from stream;
```

And then - this is the convoluted bit - remove the dummy root node by extracting the MC and MT nodes as separate CLOBs and sticking them back together:

```
select concat(x.mc.getclobval(), x.mt.getclobval())
from stream s
cross join xmltable('/xml'
  passing deletexml(xmltype('<xml>' || s.payload || '</xml>'), '//TITLE')
  columns mc xmltype path 'MC',
    mt xmltype path 'MT') x;
```

Or to update your original value use that as a subquery:

```
update stream
set payload = (
  select concat(x.mc.getclobval(), x.mt.getclobval())
  from stream s
  cross join xmltable('/xml'
    passing deletexml(xmltype('<xml>' || s.payload || '</xml>'), '//TITLE')
    columns mc xmltype path 'MC',
      mt xmltype path 'MT') x
);
```

I haven't done any correlation since you only showed one column and one row; if you have multiple rows you'd need to correlate on some ID value, and maybe only update rows that include titles.

That gives you:

```
select payload from stream;

PAYLOAD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<MC><RECORD><CODE>4995908</CODE><ROOT_CODE>380146</ROOT_CODE><MOD>229</MOD></RECORD><RECORD><CODE>69354563</CODE><ROOT_CODE>380146</ROOT_CODE><MOD>230</MOD></RECORD></MC><MT><RECORD><TYPE>LATERALITY</TYPE><TITLES>Laterality</TITLES><MOD><MODIFIER><MCS>69383650</MCS></MODIFIER></MOD></RECORD></MT>
```